# Change of Address tool - Google - how to solve migration to example.com/cs/

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, multilingual

My question is about change of domain address tool. Old domain is `example.cz`, we resolve the move to the multilingual `example.shoes` domain

`example.shoes` is domain with language mutations from different countries. On the original domain there is a redirect (301) leading to `example.shoes/cz`

However, in Change of Address tool i can´t set `example.shoes/cz` as a new domain, only root `example.shoes` can be set.

But when i am trying set `example.shoes`, the tool reports an error because redirection on `example.cz` 301 does not lead to the root domain. (because we need redirecting people direct to czech mutation)

How to solve it?

Comment: establish own Search Console properties for each language folder

Answer (score 1):

If everything else fails, how about using the `cz.example.shoes` domain instead of `example.shoes/cz`? If you cannot use subdomains, at least you can set `cz.example.shoes` as a new domain and redirect `example.cz` to `cz.example.shoes`, then redirect `cz.example.shoes` to `example.shoes/cz`. I think Google will not mind about this short redirection chain.